# Modify JQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery plugin creating a new object each time I call the plugin's main-function:

Function call:

```
new BpNotification( options );
```

Function itself:

```
function BpNotification( options ) { 
    this.init();
}

BpNotification.prototype = {
    init: function() {

        this.t = setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);

    }
}
```

Is it possible to modify this timeout-option "t" from 'outside' after the object is created?

Comment: You code is unclear and contains syntax errors at the end. In which context that setTimeout occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `t` as you like:

```
function BpNotification( options ) { 
    this.init();
}

BpNotification.prototype = {
    init: function() {
       this.t = setTimeout(function(){alert('default');}, 500);
    }
}

var Bpn = new BpNotification();
clearTimeout(Bpn.t);
Bpn.t = setTimeout(function(){alert('updated!');}, 500);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LjRzu/)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a [setter function](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) to change the setTimeout value, in the prototype object:

```
BpNotification.prototype = {
    init: function() {
    },
    updateTimeout: function(newVal){
        this.t = setTimeout(function(),newVal);
    }
};

var bpNot = new BpNotification();

bpNot.init();
bpNot.updateTimeout(10000);
```